# Flask request.form problem is always None

Tags: html, flask, post, request, get

```
def colleague_page(self, colleague_num):
    criterias = self.db.get_criterias_name(colleague_num)
    description_list = [row[1] for row in criterias]
    criterias_list = [row[0] for row in criterias]
    userinfo = self.db.get_num_record_userinfo(colleague_num)
    date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    if request.method == 'POST' and "submit_button" in request.form:
        print(request.url)
        print(request.form.get('c_0'))
        ratings = {}
        for index, criterion in enumerate(criterias_list):
            rating_key = f"{index}"
            rating = request.form.get(rating_key)
            ratings[criterion] = rating
        print(ratings)
    enumerated_criterias = list(enumerate(criterias_list))  # Compute enumerated values
    print(enumerated_criterias)
    return render_template('dashboard/colleague_page.html', description_list=description_list, 
                        userinfo=userinfo, date=date, enumerated_criterias=enumerated_criterias)
```

```
<main class="form-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Критерий</th>
                    <th>Описание</th>
                    <th>Дата оценивания</th>
                    <th>Шкала</th>
                    <th>Оценка сотрудника</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                {% for index, criterion in enumerated_criterias %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ criterion }}</td>
                    <td>{{ description_list[index] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ date }}</td>
                    <td>0-150</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" min="0" max="150" step="1" id="c_{{index}}" name="c_{{ index }}" value="1">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <form class="button" method="post">
            <button class="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit_button">Подтвердить</button>
        </form>
        {% if status %}
        <div class="status-message {{ status }}">
            {{ status_message }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </main>
```

I tried to set the numbering criteria, to contact through id. I also tried to set one name for everyone and get the value by this name. Also, through print, I output the request url to check if I am accessing the right page.

[Here is work folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUGlW.png)